# Comet without AJAX

Tags: android, comet

Suppose I only had the regular J2SE http libraries but wanted to write a 
client for comet, say in Android etc, but not limited to that, i.e. not using a WebView. Since there's no browser I'm assuming you'd have to open the long term connections yourself ... is this feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comet is only required in a browser environment. When you have access to J2ME/Android libraries you don't need to employ comet -- you simply do all what you want with full power of sockets.